# Hover on div to make action to another div with css

Tags: css, less

i have my code

```
<p class="big-number">21</p>
<p class="name">Johnny Carr</p>
```

i need any css code that when i hover on any one , change them both

```
.big-number {
        font-family: @Roboto;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #2c97de;
        text-align: center;
             &:hover {
             color: #1b71aa;
             cursor: pointer;
              + p.name{
                  color: #1b71aa;

                     }
                   }
            }
```

but its not working :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use JavaScript to do this. You can't edit different elements using CSS animation.

I'd recommend using jQuery and do this

```
$(".big-number").hover(function() {
    $("p.name").css("color", "#1b71aa");
});
```

Comment: *You can't edit different elements using CSS animation* **wrong**

Comment: Could you please show me an example instead of throwing at me that I am wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was rude... it was not my intention. All I meant is that although your answer is correct, the premise that interaction causing visual changes based on actions between elements is not restricted to JS. It can also be accomplished by css, just not in the specific case of this question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without using any outside libraries would be to nest them within the same `div` and give the `hover` and `color` properties to all its children.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned this can't be done exactly as you are asking because CSS can't modify elements that come before them as far as I know. You could have name update when big-number is hovered but not the other way around.

```css
.big-number:hover ~ .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="big-number">21</p>
<p class="name">Johnny Carr</p>
```

As jxmorris12 mentioned I'd just wrap these in another element and hover on that instead.

```css
.selected:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section class='selected'>
  <p class="big-number">21</p>
  <p class="name">Johnny Carr</p>
</section>

<section class='selected'>
  <p class="big-number">21</p>
  <p class="name">Johnny Carr</p>
</section>
```